# What does status code -11 from the pyomo couenne solver mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ampl, pyomo

I am using `pyomo` for an optimization problem, and keep getting the following error returned from the solver: `Solver (asl) returned non-zero return code (-11)`:

```
ERROR: "[base]/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py", 578, solve
    Solver (asl) returned non-zero return code (-11)
ERROR: "[base]/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py", 583, solve
    Solver log:
    Couenne 0.5.6 -- an Open-Source solver for Mixed Integer Nonlinear Optimization
    Mailing list: couenne@list.coin-or.org
    Instructions: http://www.coin-or.org/Couenne
```

I am trying to find out:

- What does this return code mean?
- Why did it not exit normally?

The problem defined in pyomo is long, so I will try to avoid posting all of the code here, but essentially:

- I am using a `ConcreteModel`
- I am using the `couenne` solver (i.e. I pass `name=”couenne”` to the `SolverFactory`)
- The objective function is fairly simple, but there are many constraints and many variables

Other info:

- I am using python 2.7,
- pyomo version `4.4.1`
- I downloaded the binary solvers for couenne from here: https://www.coin-or.org/download/binary/Couenne/
- I am able to solve very simple `ConcreteModel`s using `pyomo`/`couenne`, so I doubt it is an issue with compilation of the solver.
- I am using MacOSX

How do I find out what this return code means? Or generally how to debug this? The solver is largely a black box unfortunately... and I don't see any warnings about the way I'm using it.

Comment: Is there a list of return codes/status codes for `pyomo`/`AMPL`/`asl` solver, which I assume are all using the same thing?

Comment: "A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (Unix only)." (from [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects)); signal 11 is SEGFAULT, so most probably the child process died due to a segmentation fault. Either you provided an unexpected set of arguments, or it was compiled incorrectly, or you spotted a bug.

Comment: Okay, thank you @MatteoItalia.  I have a few questions: how do you know "signal 11 is SEGFAULT"?  Where do I find the set of arguments provided to the solver and see if they are correct?

Comment: 1. Because I've seen it way too many times in my programs. :-) But it is also detailed into `man 7 signal`. 2. No idea, sorry.

Comment: If you can find the site-packages directed where Pyomo is installed, look for the file pyomo/pyomo/solvers/plugins/solvers/ASL.py. In that file, just before the return statement of the `create_command_line` method, add something like `print(' '.join(cmd))` and this will show the command-line statement that is used to launch the solver.

Comment: Also, the version of Pyomo you are using is fairly outdated. The latest release is 5.2. Not saying that will magically fix this, but there have been many bug fixes since then.

Comment: Is the new version backwards compatible?